# MS Word: Replace bookmark Text in a Userform instead of Adding using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

VBA Newbie here.

I've just created a userform that allows my team to create a cover letter.

The button below appears in the body of the document in an "Instruction" section. When they click on it, it shows my form which they need to fill out.

```
Private Sub EditFormButt_Click()
    CoverLetterForm.Show
End Sub
```

The Form currently has pre-filled placeholder text. I want my team to be able to *replace* the text. Right now, what happens is, when they click my "OK" Button (code to follow), the placeholder text remains, and their new text is added.

For example:

> To: Mr. Paul Daniels **Ms. Sarah Jones**
>   
> 21 New Order Street
>   
> London
>   
> England
>   
> Dear Mr. Paul Daniels **Ms. Sarah Jones**

Ms. Sarah Jones is the Placeholder Text, Mr. Paul Daniels is the updated text.

I need any new entries to *replace* whatever is in the Placeholder text, but not delete anything that hasn't been updated, as sometimes, they may only want to change the name of recipient but not the person's address. This is also useful if they want to correct any mistakes they may have made in spelling without having to start a totally new document.

Here is my OKButt Code:

```
Private Sub OKButt_Click()
    Dim bmRecName As Range
    Set bmRecName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmRecName").Range
    bmRecName.Text = Me.RecName.Value
    Dim bmRecAddress As Range
    Set bmRecAddress = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmRecAddress").Range
    bmRecAddress.Text = Me.RecAddress.Value
    CoverLetterForm.Hide
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It's not quite clear how things are set up in the document... Where are the bookmarks in relation to the "placeholder text"? I'm guessing they're next to the text, not surrounding the text? Try selecting placeholder text and adding the bookmark to the selection so that the bookmark *contains* the selection. Use a different bookmark for each item (i.e. not the entire address in one bookmark).

Comment: Hello Cindy, the placeholder text is pre-filled in the UserForm. I have found a way by adding the following to each Range `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "bmRecName", BMRecName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler:

```
Private Sub OKButt_Click()
Dim bmRng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set bmRng = .Bookmarks("bmRecName").Range
  bmRng.Text = Me.RecName.Value
  .Bookmarks.Add "bmRecName", bmRng
  Set bmRng = .Bookmarks("bmRecAddress").Range
  bmRng.Text = Me.RecAddress.Value
  .Bookmarks.Add "bmRecAddress", bmRng
  CoverLetterForm.Hide
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've found the answer, but if anyone has a more elegant solution, I'm all ears!

```
Private Sub OKButt_Click()
    Dim bmRecName As Range
    Set bmRecName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmRecName").Range
    bmRecName.Text = Me.RecName.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "bmRecName", bmRecName
    Dim bmRecAddress As Range
    Set bmRecAddress = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmRecAddress").Range
    bmRecAddress.Text = Me.RecAddress.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "bmRecAddress", bmRecAddress
    CoverLetterForm.Hide
End Sub
```

Basically adding the following code:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "bmRecAddress", bmRecAddress
```